# three.js merge geometry and memory consumption

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a viewer right now that supports working with models with about 1.5 million vertices. We are using  THREE.ObjectLoader to load JSON-files. Our models are using instancing for objects that has the same  material and objects.

To support larger models i started to look into merging geometry. I used days reading about it and looked at examples. The merging worked great for my needs but i noticed that the consumption of memory went up. The same model with merging started to consume about 80-150% more memory. I fear that our viewers limits are not going to be FPS but out of memory. It kinda makes sense when i think about it because you have bigger geometries with merging while instancing is using the same geometry.

Maybe my googling skills are not sufficient enough, but i haven't found much information about this.Is this the trade-off for using merging vs instancing? Or am i missing something?

Comment: Take a look at the code for merging. All it's doing is tacking on data to an existing object. Let's call your objects `target` and `adding`. After calling `target.merge(adding)`, the data from `adding` is duplicated--still as the original `adding`, and now also as data in `target`. Deallocating `adding` should free some of that extra memory you're encountering.

Comment: Why would you merge if you can instance? Merging wont help unless you have thousands and thousands of objects, and are getting overhead from issuing drawcalls.

Comment: ah ok i understand. Thanks for the explanation @TheJim01.

Comment: @pailhead yea but that's just the case for me. We have like 2k-5k draw calls and it will increase even more when supporting larger models.